# Equivalent of find ** in Sublime Text 3

Tags: find-and-replace, sublime-text-3

I would like to search all files in a subdirectory where the filenames match an expression (e.g. `*.html`) in my project.

In zsh or Vim one would use an expression like this:

```
subdirectory/**/*.html
```

Is there an equivalent with the Sublime Text 3 search and replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open the Find/Replace bar
2. Click the **...** button next to the **Where** field and **Add Folder**
3. Browse to `subdirectory/`
4. Click the **...** button next to the **Where** field and **Add Include Filter**
5. Replace the auto-filled `*.txt` part of the **Where** field with `*.html`
6. Fill out the **Find** and **Replace** fields as you desire, and click either **Find** or **Replace** buttons to the right of the fields.

This will result in a **Where** expression such as:

```
subdirectory/,*.html
```

Comment: Awesome - much appreciated.